# How to check if the comma exist in helm charts?

Tags: charts, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'd like to use some code like below to describe a comma is the substring of the string.

```
{{- if contains '\,' .alias }}
```

But it reports the error in the line when using `helm lint`

```
 invalid syntax
```

How to write it correctly?

Comment: Did you try with `","` double quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to community user [Bimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57926732/how-to-check-if-the-comma-exist-in-helm-charts#).

It can be applied like:

```
{{- if contains "," .Values.xxx.name }}
  some_data: {{ .Values.xxx.name }}
{{- end }}
```

For further reference please follow [String Functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html):